# Why are the D3D12 samples using WM_PAINT?

Tags: direct3d12

If you're trying to program a game, you really shouldn't wait around for `WM_PAINT` signals from the O/S to draw. You should repeatedly draw as quickly as possible.

Why then in the D3D sample code is [rendering happening in `WM_PAINT`?](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld/src/HelloTriangle/Win32Application.cpp#L107)

How can I rework the D3D12 sample to render *as quickly as possible*, without waiting for `WM_PAINT` signals from the O/S?

Answer (score 4):

The "Hello, World" DirectX 12 sample on [GitHub: DirectX-Graphics-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/) is relying on the fact that if you call `PeekMessage` and there is no other message available, it *creates* one `WM_PAINT` message:

```
MSG msg = {};
while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    // Process any messages in the queue.
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint).

Typically game render loops don't rely on the "magic WM_PAINT" behavior, and that what I have in [GitHub: directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/):

```
MSG msg = {};
while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        g_game->Tick();
    }
}

g_game.reset();
```

and the only thing `WM_PAINT` does is clear the screen--with special handling for resizing:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    if (s_in_sizemove && game)
    {
        game->Tick();
    }
    else
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        (void)BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

> Here `Tick` is a method which does the `Update` and `Render`, but depending on the mode of `StepTimer` it may call `Update` more than once per frame.

In the end, both Win32 'message pumps' achieve basically the same thing.

Comment: Actually, I just remembered that you're supposed to call `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` in order to signal to Win O/S that you've painted your window. What I think is happening is the `WM_PAINT` message is being resent over and over again, because the client area is not being validated because calls to `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` are missing